# @ConfigurationProperties on fields

Tags: java, properties, spring-boot

When defining properties with `@ConfigurationProperties`, can I define the prefix of a specific field instead of the whole class?

For example, let's say we have a Properties class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.example")
public class MyProperties {
    private String host;
    private String port;
    // Geters and setters...
}
```

This will bind the fields `host` and `port` to `com.example.host` and `com.example.port`. Let's say I want to bind `port` to `com.example.something.port`. The way to do this is to define an Inner class `Something` and add the property `port` there. But if I need more prefixes it will become too cumbersome. I tried to add `@ConfigurationProperties` on the setter because the target of the annotation is `ElementType.TYPE` and `ElementType.METHOD`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.example.something.port")
public void setPort(int port) {...}
```

But it did not work in the end. Is there another way to customise the prefix except via Inner classes?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to map single property, just use `@Value` annotation.
2. If you have groups, e.g. like these:

   test1.property1=...
   test1.test2.property2=...
   test1.test2.property3=...

You can use

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:myapp.properties")
public class ApplicationProperties {

    private String property1;
    private Test2 test2;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test2")
    public static class Test2 {
        @NotNull
        private String property2;
        @NotNull
        private String property3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use the `@Value` annotation?

Comment: @Value annotation is in case you have simple values. That is not explained in example, as it is notoriously known construct. If you need example anyway, let me know and I will add it here

Comment: Sorry I over read that you explain 2 different approaches, I thought this was a single solution.